# execute exe file through ecec() and then send the console (.exe) in background

Tags: java

i want to run a specified file (.exes) in background...

```
File file = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\demo\\calc.exe");  
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

what if i use Runtime stuff

Answer (score 0):

*Executes the specified string command in a separate process.*

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\demo\\calc.exe");
```

Comment: my program is running perfectly.. it is opening exe file but now i want to send this process(exe) in background where it continues to run

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` it creates seperate process

Comment: i know sir, but what i have to do, to send this child process in background

Answer (score 0):

You could execute your process in another thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
    } catch (Exception e) { ... }
  }
}
thread.start();
```